# Trying to match adverbs ending with ly but not comparative/superlative forms

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have the following adverbs:

```
fastly onffly fly incomprehensibly totaly happily 

lily sly more happily 

most seriously
```

I would like to match only normal form of adverb ending with ly, not comparative and superlative that end with ly.

The above example, I dont want to match a word ending with *ly* if the previous word is *more* or *most*.

I tried to do this:

```
(?:^[more|most])\s?\w*ly
```

But I am not getting any match. Any idea? [demo that I tried to rework.](https://regex101.com/r/aTiDsM/1/)

Comment: I am not sure that regular expressions is what you are after here.... you might need a Natural Language Processing (NLP) library.

Comment: Try `(?<!more |most )\b\w*ly`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypx16D/1). Or even `(?<!\bmore |\bmost )\b\w*ly`

Comment: I am trying without libraries. Want to learn regex to the core.

Comment: If you are using regex there is some regex library behind the scenes. There is no "universal regex". [This one](https://regex101.com/r/gG50rK/1) - `\b(?:more|most)\s+\w*ly(*SKIP)(*F)|\w*ly` - will only work with PCRE library, e.g.

Comment: very interesting @WiktorStribiżew. Lots of learning here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "universal regex" and if you are using regex there is some regex library behind the scenes. In your case, you experimented with PCRE regex library, so you may consider either

```
\b(?<!\bmore |\bmost )\w*ly\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypx16D/5). Or, a [SKIP-FAIL regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
\b(?:more|most)\s+\w*ly(*SKIP)(*F)|\w*ly\b
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypx16D/4).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\bmore |\bmost )` - there should be no whole word `more` or `most` followed with 1 space immediately before the current location
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `ly\b` - `ly` word ending (`ly` followed with a word boundary).

In the SKIP-FAIL regex, `\b(?:more|most)\s+\w*ly` matches all `more` and `most` `~ly` word combindations, discards them and matches words with `ly` suffix in other locations.